# How to Decode Badly Formatted JSON in Swift using Codable

Tags: json, swift, codable, yelp

I am trying to decode the Yelp REST API business search response in Swift using codable. I have managed to decode this using the traditional method of serializing the response into a NSDictionary and just marshaling objects using values from the dictionary; however, as an exercise to myself I am trying to refactor the code to use the Codable protocols and JSONDecoder() in Swift. Yelp really wrote a shitty API and this is the response that I need to decode:

```
 { 
businesses =     (
                {
            alias = "dos-caminos-new-york-7";
            categories =             (
                                {
                    alias = mexican;
                    title = Mexican;
                },
                                {
                    alias = bars;
                    title = Bars;
                }
            );
            coordinates =             {
                latitude = "40.7593727";
                longitude = "-73.9853281";
            };
            "display_phone" = "(212) 918-1330";
            distance = "55.57057440108928";
            id = 2iwT3iutZvmqzmu7oOkWFw;
            "image_url" = "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/eHvXPqv6iLcTXfT486z6JA/o.jpg";
            "is_closed" = 0;
            location =             {
                address1 = "1567 Broadway";
                address2 = "";
                address3 = "";
                city = "New York";
                country = US;
                "display_address" =                 (
                    "1567 Broadway",
                    "New York, NY 10036"
                );
                state = NY;
                "zip_code" = 10036;
            };
            name = "Dos Caminos";
            phone = "+12129181330";
            price = "$$";
            rating = "3.5";
            "review_count" = 644;
            transactions =             (
                delivery,
                pickup
            );
            url = "https://www.yelp.com/biz/dos-caminos-new-york-7?adjust_creative=RzPd81IBxDPwaWBeNhRk8w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=RzPd81IBxDPwaWBeNhRk8w";
        },
                {
            alias = "bond-45-new-york-2";
            categories =             (
                                {
                    alias = italian;
                    title = Italian;
                },
                                {
                    alias = pizza;
                    title = Pizza;
                },
                                {
                    alias = newamerican;
                    title = "American (New)";
                }
            );
            coordinates =             {
                latitude = "40.7591637016814";
                longitude = "-73.9859788257256";
            };
            "display_phone" = "(212) 869-4545";
            distance = "77.44246334243893";
            id = "8-Ug0Zjs5sL6MARspRJ7CA";
            "image_url" = "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/CEfwtx0YtfDGog0hWmQ72A/o.jpg";
            "is_closed" = 0;
            location =             {
                address1 = "221 W 46th St";
                address2 = "";
                address3 = "";
                city = "New York";
                country = US;
                "display_address" =                 (
                    "221 W 46th St",
                    "New York, NY 10036"
                );
                state = NY;
                "zip_code" = 10036;
            };
            name = "Bond 45";
            phone = "+12128694545";
            price = "$$";
            rating = "3.5";
            "review_count" = 755;
            transactions =             (
                delivery,
                pickup
            );
            url = "https://www.yelp.com/biz/bond-45-new-york-2?adjust_creative=RzPd81IBxDPwaWBeNhRk8w&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=RzPd81IBxDPwaWBeNhRk8w";
        }
    );
    region =     {
        center =         {
            latitude = "40.758896";
            longitude = "-73.98513";
        };
    };
    total = 5300;
}
```

The top level object has a value of businesses which has a list? of Businesses that I want to create. I have created the corresponding Swift Codable structs as such:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var businesses: [Business]
    
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case businesses
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        // ERROR: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "businesses", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))).
        businesses = try values.decode([Business].self, forKey: .businesses)
        
        print("values is \(values.allKeys)")
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
     //TODO
    }
}
```

and

```
struct Business: Codable {
    var name: String
    var category:
    var latitude: Double = 0.0
    var longitude: Double = 0.0
    var phoneNumber: String = ""
    var distance: Double = 0.0
    var imageURL: String = ""
    var price: Price
    var yelpURL: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "name"
        case category = "categories"
        case coordinates = "coordinates"
        case phoneNumber = "phone"
        case distance = "distance"
        case imageURL = "image_url"
        case price = "price"
        case yelpURL = "url"
    }
    
    enum CategoryCodingKey: String, CodingKey {
        case alias = "alias"
        case title = "title"
    }
    
    enum CoordinateInfoKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case latitude = "latitude"
        case longitude = "longitude"
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        // TODO, will add more here but the error is not really here
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    }
}
```

The error that I get when I try to run this code is in a comment in the `Response` struct above. It seems to me that the YELP API is formatted in such a way that the value for businesses is not a list of objects but some other type that Swift does not recognize. How do I go about using Codable to decode this Response into the Response struct that will hold a list of Businesses? Is this even possible with the way the YELP API has been setup?

Comment: Print the json string returned by the API `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")` then edit your question and add the json to it. The NSDictionary printed is useless

Comment: Wow...im dumb that actually alone helped a lot. I see the JSON object a lot better now.

Comment: You can also use`.decodeIfPresent` instead of `decode` so that decoder will not throw an error on entire object but rather making your notDecodable object nil. It is especially usefull when you lets say expect something to be of type "String" , but it will be of type "Int" Here is an example: `name = try? values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)`